# Как высчитать скидку?

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

Всем привет. Есть 3 таблицы - Скидки(Discount), Клиенты(Clients) и Заказы(Orders)

Discount

```
id_discount count_orders percent_discount
     1           5             1,5
     2           10            2,5
```

Clients

```
id_client  Name Surname
     1     Ivan  Petrov
     2     Vasya Vasev
```

Orders

```
id   order_sum id_client
```

Вопрос, как посчитать общую сумму, учитывая количество заказов, который сделал клиент? Если общее кол-во заказов 5 и выше, то идет скидка в 1.5%, если 10 и выше, то 2.5%. В противном случае скидки нет.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebird нет под руками, так что пишу максимально приближенный к стандартам запрос, сработает с высокой вероятностью. Вы не указали к какой конкретно сумме вы хотите применить скидку, поэтому посчитал, что следует выдать все заказы, вычислив для каждого из них сумму со скидкой, с предположением что в данный момент в заказах сумма без скидки.

```
select O.id,O.id_client,
       O.order_sum-(O.order_sum/100*coalesce(D.percent_discount,0))
  from Orders O
  left join
       (select id_client,max(D.count_orders) as d_cnt
          from (select id_client,count(1) as cnt from Orders
                 group by id_client) as C,
               Discount as D
         where D.count_orders<=cnt
         group by id_client) as S
    on S.id_client=O.id_client
  left join Discount as D
    on D.count_orders=S.d_cnt
```

1. Подзапрос *C* выбирает текущие количества заказов по клиентам
2. К ним клеются все скидки с меньшим или равным количеством
3. Подзапрос *S*. Берется количество для скидки для максимально подошедшего кол-ва заказов
4. По left (т.к. скидки может и не быть) доклеиваются скидки с учетом нужного количества

Таблицу clients приклеить по желанию.